Koi or goldfish?
How to differentiate between a koi and a goldfish? As far as I know, both are carp. So is it a big goldfish or a small koi?


http://fishgirlwrites.blogspot.com/2012/11/differences-between-goldfish-and-koi.html your picture show koi,goldfish have a shorter body and no barbels and the underside of the jaw is more rounded in goldfish,the information is easy to find online so i post this as a comment not an answer.

Koi generally have much larger price tags too.
